# why is my elastic beanstalk instance being replaced when I deploy?

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a docker based elastic beanstalk environment, hosting a ruby on rails web application. The environment is a single instance box.
whenever I issue an `eb deploy` command, elastic beanstalk terminates the instance and launches a new one. I was expecting that EB would launch a new container in the same instance and swap it with the old one.
This instance termination is causing downtime. **Is there an automated way to deploy docker into elastic beanstalk without downtime?**
the only solution I found was the "swap URLs" feature. but I found it cumbersome.

Comment: What all did you change in your deployment? Not all deployments require instance termination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under your configuration settings for your Elastic Beanstalk environment you will find **Updates and Deployments**. Under **Application Deployments** you can set the *Batch type* to meet your requirements.

For this process you will be required to increase your running instances to at least two.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an automated way to deploy docker into elastic beanstalk without downtime?

1. Push a new docker image to the same dockerbub/dockerregistry repository with the same tag that you used in elastic beanstalk.
2. Change the Beanstalk size to 2 to launch a new server with the new version of your docker container.
3. Terminate the older instance and allow EB to replace it, wait until replacement becomes healthy.*
4. Change EB size back to 1.

* If your do not let the second instance get healthy when your reduce size to 1 it may terminate the healthy one.

Comment: wow, that's one hell of a workaround. I was shooting for something internal to EB.

Comment: The other alternative is to have 2 stacks. Deploy to the one not used and then switch DNS